# Use querySelectorAll to grab class names and handle on change events

Tags: javascript

So I have the below image showing that when either one of the checkboxes is clicked, the hidden div will be shown and it both are clicked, it will still show which is exactly what I want.

**The below video does exactly what it needs to do - [WORKS PERFECTLY]**:
[image]

**On hard refresh, it saves the checkboxes and remembers to show the hidden div - [WORKS PERFECTLY]:**
[image]

**Here is the code that belongs to the above JavaScript reference - [CODE WORKS PERFECTLY]**:

```
function rtd3Transaction() {
    if (document.getElementById('rtd3Transaction').checked || document.getElementById('rtd3Device').checked) {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
    } else {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Transaction);
document.getElementById('rtd3Transaction').addEventListener('change', rtd3Transaction);

function rtd3Device() {
    if (document.getElementById('rtd3Transaction').checked || document.getElementById('rtd3Device').checked) {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
    } else {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none'
        formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
    }
}
document.getElementById('rtd3Device').addEventListener('change', rtd3Device);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Device);
```

.
.

---

.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve, so instead of using on change calls based on ID in my html code, I wanted to base it off a class name.

**Small details**:
Both of the input fields in the HTML have the `rtd3_change` class added to them.

`formWrapperCertainSelection` is the id added to the hidden div.

So here is the code at my attempt to wanting to use the querySelectorAll action:

```
function rtd3Confirmation() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".rtd3_change").forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (item.checked) {
                formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
                formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
            } else {
                formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none';
                formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
            }
        })
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Confirmation);
```

**Here are the issues that I'm having**:

- On hard refresh, the hidden section is not shown if either of the checkboxes is checked.
- If at least one checkbox is checked, the hidden section is still not shown.

**Please use the below video for reference**:
[image]

Would appreciate all the help I can get on this - Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot check if the hard refresh is working because you didn't mention how you save the state. But this code will probably give you the hints you need to procede. Plz comment if you need anything further explained or if it don't work as you intended.

```js
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change');

function rtd3Confirmation() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change:checked').length) {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
    } else {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
    }
}

for (var inputElement of inputElements) {
  inputElement.addEventListener('change', rtd3Confirmation);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Confirmation);
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input id="rtd3Transaction" type="checkbox" class="rtd3_change">My data transaction</p>
  <p><input id="rtd3Device" type="checkbox" class="rtd3_change">Information device</p>
  </div>
  <p id="formWrapperCertainSelection"><input id="formWrapperConfirm">Confirm</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having issues using this on IE11 since `for of` isn't supported - Is there an alternative method>?

Comment: Just use a default for loop or convert it to an arrayband use forEach

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your event callback looks at each input in isolation, not as a pair with a collective state. So as soon as one is unchecked, the hidden area is hidden, regardless of whether the other input is still checked.

The following solves that problem, and is also shorter code. It also has the benefit of working for any number of inputs, by delegating the event rather than binding the event to each input separately.

```
function rtd3Confirmation() {
    let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change')];
    document.body.addEventListener('change', evt => {
        if (!inputs.includes(evt.target)) return;
        let checked = inputs.filter(el => el.checked);
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = checked.length ? '' : 'none';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = !!checked.length;
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Confirmation);
```